# Unity 3D game for coder

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, ide, field

So, I have to build an IDE inside Unity 3D. So far I made a canvas, panel, input field, image and a text on the image. So... my question is how to dynamically show the line numbers on the left side? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your input field's line type is set as **'Multiline New Line'**. Get the text from **OnValueChanged** event of your input field. Split the string by **'\n'**. You will get the array of lines. The length of that array is number of lines in your input field. Add 1 to that length value & use it as your last line number.

Comment: Alright, I was thinking about something similar actually, but now the problem with the letters in the left remains, what happens when the new line rows exceed the limit of the grey bar? Probably it can fit around 14-15 numbers, what if the code is 20 rows?

Comment: Grey bar needs to be simple text component with Vertical Overflow. Keep adding new number as the text changes in input field.